# Pointwise and uniform convergence of series of functions

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

Consider power series $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^n$.

Let $\alpha = \limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} \vert c_n\vert^{1/n}$. Recall radius of convergence $r=1/\alpha$.

(i) Assume $r>0$. Show that $f(x)$ converges pointwise for $\vert x\vert < r$ and does not converge for $\vert x\vert>r$.

(ii) Show that $f(x)$ converges uniformly on any interval $[-s,s] \subset (-r,r)$ and show this implies $f(x)$ is continuous on $(-r,r)$.

I didn't know what $\limsup$ was until I googled it. I thought radius of convergence is related to $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left | \frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}\right |\dots$ Is this equivalent to the $\alpha$ defined above in the question??

I don't really know what I'm meant to do for (i). Isn't it the definition of 'radius of convergence' $r$ that we get convergence for $\vert x\vert <r$? How do you "show" this??

Don't have much clue about (ii) either.

Comment: Probably you need to show that the radius of convergence is given by $r = 1/\alpha$.